100 prisoners problem with n < 50
In the 100 prisoners problem, I understand that when $l \geq 51$, the number of permutations is $100!/l$.
However how to calculate the exact number of permutations when $l < 51$?
When $l = 1$, the permutation is $1$, as there is only $1$ way.
What about when $l = 2$, $l = 10$, or $l = 49$?
Is there a formula which helps generate the bar graph (the green portion of survival probability)


It looks like you are inquiring about the cycle structure of the Symmetric group.  This is a well-studied part of combinatorics, suggesting you might find some real expertise in the matter on the [Math.SE] site.

OEIS A126074 deals with this.  For $100$ prisoners, you want the values in rows $4951-5050$ of https://oeis.org/A126074/b126074.txt
